# New to CSS, issues with nav bar

Tags: css

I am new to CSS and can't work out a kink. I am having several issues with my nav css. The hover state is not inline with the normal state, and the last item is pushed onto a new line rather than equally spacing across a single bar.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HBXku/356/)

```
ul {
    left: 20%;
    top: 10%;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: radial-gradient(circle, #505050, #3E3E3E);
    width: 50%;
}

li {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    width: 24%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border-right: 1px solid #232323;
}

/* Remove border from last tab */
li:last-child {
    border: none;
}

li:first-child {
    border: none;
}

/* Setting up the text on the menu */
li a {
    text-align: center;
    font: Verdana;
    font-size: 16px;
    display: inline-block;
    color: #EAE0D2;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 20px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 25%;
}

/* Change the link color on hover */
li a:hover {

    background: linear-gradient(#2B2B2B, #232323);
    border:none;
    width: 83%;
}

/* Color the active tab */
.active {
    background: linear-gradient(#3E3E3E, #2B2B2B);
    color: #white;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am new to CSS

Welcome onboard then!

To create a multiple row layout you may want to use `flexbox`, it's quite easy. See below an example and the explanations on how it's working:

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: radial-gradient(circle, #505050, #3E3E3E);
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  flex-basis: 25%;
  border-right: 1px solid #232323;
  text-align: center;
}


/* Remove border from last tab */

li:last-child {
  border: none;
}

li:first-child {
  border: none;
}


/* Setting up the text on the menu */

li a {
  display: inline-block;
  font: Verdana;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #EAE0D2;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 20px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}


/* Change the link color on hover */

li:hover {
  background: linear-gradient(#2B2B2B, #232323);
}


/* Color the active tab */

.active {
  background: linear-gradient(#3E3E3E, #2B2B2B);
  color: #white;
}
```

```html
<ul id="menu">
  <li class="active"><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">GALLERY</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">ART</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
</ul>
```

### Wait, what?

1. We first set the container to `display: flex`
2. Then, tanks to `flex-basis: 25%`, we tell every element of the container (`ul li {...}`) to fit 25% of the total width of the container.
3. We move the `text-align: center` from `ul {...}` to `ul li {...}` and remove the `width: 25%` from `li a {...}` so the text inside the list items is correctly justified.

**EDIT:**
And finally (to fix hover issues), we change

```
li a:hover {
  background: linear-gradient(#2B2B2B, #232323);
  border:none;
  width: 83%;
}
```

to

```
li:hover {
  background: linear-gradient(#2B2B2B, #232323);
}
```

Comment: Very interesting, a cleaner approach for sure! However, I still have an alignment issue going on with the hover?

Comment: Excellent response! Very informational and easy to see what has changed.

Comment: Wou're welcome. Think about closing your thread if the solution worked :)

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with the ***Flexbox*** and much less code:

```css
/* basic CSS browser reset */
* {margin:0;padding:0;box-sizing:border-box}
html, body {width:100%;height:100%}

/* can comment out if you decide to use the below approach */
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center; /* horizontal alignment / centering */
  align-items: flex-start; /* prevents the #menu to fill the remaining height of the body */
}

#menu {
  display: flex; /* displays children inline */
  align-items: flex-start;
  width: 50%; /* added */
  margin-top: 10%; /* added */
  /* alternative to center the #menu horizontally, in this case you don't need the styling on the body element
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  */
  list-style-type: none;
  background: radial-gradient(circle, #505050, #3E3E3E);
}

li {
  flex: 1; /* each takes as much width as it can, i.e. each 25% width of the parent */
  border-right: 1px solid #232323;
}

li:last-child {
  border: none;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  font: Verdana;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #EAE0D2;
  padding: 20px 0;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
  background: linear-gradient(#2B2B2B, #232323);
}

.active {
  background: linear-gradient(#3E3E3E, #2B2B2B);
}
```

```html
<ul id="menu">
  <li class="active"><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">GALLERY</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">ART</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

excuse me for my bad english.

first to get your last button inline you must change the box model on your list items, and set back your 4 buttons to 25%

```
li { 
   box-sizing: border-box;
   width:25%; ...
```

now your 1px borders don't break your alignment anymore

then same issue with your anchors in the list items, change the box model and correct the width

```
li a { 
      box-sizing: border-box;
      width: 100%; //the whole width of the parent li
```

now that's your padding which  are no longer a problem

you can now delete the width in li a:hover

> width: 83%

everything should be fine

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/albanblanchard/8z78ms31/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Another approach to the others would be to calculate the widths minus the border like so:

```
li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  width: calc( 25% - 3px ); /* 1px per border as specified */
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border-right: 1px solid #232323;
}
```

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, I didn't consider the borders.

Comment: @KevinP. if you do continue with this method you might also want to look in to box-sizing "box-sizing: border-box;"

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp

Answer (score 0):

change your width in li to 24%

```
width:24%;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HBXku/360/

Update: you have li a set to a width of 25% so the link was only 25% of the size of the box. i changed it to 80% and it works fine.

Comment: I thought this as well but the li was already set to 24%. In the fiddle it changes to 25% automatically.

Comment: hmmm i thought that would be it for sure

Comment: Ah, it appears it's the border of 1px that is shifting it?